# VB.NET get average from a range of values from a sortedlist (sortedlist.average)

Tags: vb.net, average, sortedlist

I have a sortedlist like this;

```
public MeasuredValues as SortedList(Of DateTime, Double)
```

I throw in a bunch of values. For example;

```
MeasuredValues.add(New DateTime(2010, 1, 1),33)
MeasuredValues.add(New DateTime(2011, 1, 1),13)
MeasuredValues.add(New DateTime(2012, 1, 1),233)
MeasuredValues.add(New DateTime(2013, 1, 1),331)
MeasuredValues.add(New DateTime(2014, 1, 1),732)
MeasuredValues.add(New DateTime(2015, 1, 1),123)
```

Now I want to get the avarage of this values, say from 2011 to 2013. (ofcourse my real situation has much more values)

I've seen the sortedlist has a extension method called 'Avarage' ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534965(v=vs.110).aspx

But I can't find any clear examples. I like VB.NET, but C# examples are also welcome...

I know I need to implement a function, but I don't know how. MSDN does not supply any example. Also, is this the best/fastest way to do it?, or is there a better alternative...

Thanks in advance...

---

Update:
I've tried this;

```
            Dim MyAverage As Double = MeasuredValues.Average(Function(measure) CDate(measure.Key) >= ThisStepBeginTime And CDate(measure.Key) <= ThisStepEndTime)
```

But it only delivers a occasional -0,1

This 'one-line functions' are new for me, what am I doing wrong?

---

Update 2:
My example was a over simplefied example of the real problem. I'm trying to draw a graph, where every pixel represents a timespan. Like this;

```
    For XCounter As Integer = 0 To MyBase.Width
        Dim ThisStepBeginTime As DateTime = First.AddTicks(XCounter * TimeStep.Ticks)
        Dim ThisStepEndTime As DateTime = First.AddTicks((XCounter + 1) * TimeStep.Ticks)

        For Each MySerie In Me.AllSeries.Values

            Dim MyAverage As Double = MySerie.Where(Function(measure) CDate(measure.Key) >= ThisStepBeginTime And CDate(measure.Key) <= ThisStepEndTime).Average(Function(measure) measure.Value)

            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, XCounter, CInt((Me.Height / MySerie.HighestValue) * MyAverage), XCounter, 0)
        Next
    Next
```

This results in;

```
Sequence contains no elements
```

Because some of the steps don't have a value....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can filter the list first and then get the average:

```
MeasuredValues _
.Where(Function(measure) cDate(measure.Key) >= dateFrom And cDate(measure.Key) <= dateTo) _
.Average(Function(measure) measure.Value)
```

---

REGARDING UPDATE 2:

If I understand the new issue corrently, you're getting an error on the `Average` if `Where` returns no elements. I know you can add `.DefaultIfEmpty` in between however I don't know how that would affect the `Average` function:

```
MeasuredValues _
.Where(Function(measure) cDate(measure.Key) >= dateFrom And cDate(measure.Key) <= dateTo) _
.DefaultIfEmpty() _
.Average(Function(measure) measure.Value)
```

I'm expecting the `DefaultIfEmpty` to return an empty element `Of(DateTime, double)` and thus averaging to 0

Comment: You don't need to call `Where` and then `Average`.  You can call just `Average` and pass the filter, i.e. the lambda that you would otherwise pass to `Where`, as a second argument.

Comment: Thanks Jmcilhinney, you are right again, as usual. (I know you from the vbforums)

Comment: I see you edited your question after i posted my answer... @Lectere did my code not work for you?

Comment: That's why I edited it, it worked partially, thats what I wrote in my edit;

Comment: but the code you provided in the edit is a combination of the Where and Average. The Average inner function requires to 'return' a numeric value but you're returning a boolean. Thats why I like to split things and keeping them simple... The where wants a boolean expression and the average wants a numeric value...

Comment: oh and the results you're getting are 0 and -1 because they're the int values of true and false... its getting the average when 0, the majority are in the data range and when -1, the majority are outside the date range

Comment: Keith, you where right, you totally understand my problem and helped me very good. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On little thing; sometimes there are no values; Sequence contains no elements

Comment: you're welcome :) If you would like, update the question with the latest code and sample data (date range) and I'll take a look :)

Comment: Since the key should already be a DateTime, is `cDate` necessary?